# First Order Linear Recurrences with loops (summation)

Tags: recurrence

I have the following recurrence:

> T(n) = Σ<sub>k=0</sub><sup>n-1</sup> T(k) + n + 3

My professor says this simplifies to

> T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + 1

How is this possible?

Comment: To clarify, which recurrence is the one you're looking at - the one in the code, T(n) = sum from k = 0 to n-1 T(k) + n + 3?

Comment: Give yourself a small input and then pretend to be the computer. Follow the coded instructions and work through the program on paper. This will probably be more useful to you in the long run than an answer here.

Comment: @user4581301 The question here seems to be more of a math problem than a coding question - I'm not sure that tracing through the code by hand would help explain how to arrive at the given recurrence relation.

Comment: @templatetypedef true enough. I was approaching more from the "How does this work?" side of things rather than the "Why does this work?"

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm looking at the summation from k=0 to n-1 of T(k) + n + 3, this part is correct. I just don't understand how I went from that to T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simplification is not correct. These recurrences give different values back.

You didn't specify a base case for the recurrence, so let's assume the base case is T(0). Then we have

- T(0) = T(0)
- T(1) = T(0) + 1 + 3 = T(0) + 4
- T(2) = T(0) + (T(0) + 4) + 2 + 3 = 2T(0) + 9
- T(3) = T(0) + (T(0) + 4) + (2T(0) + 9) + 3 + 3 = 4T(0) + 19
- ...
- T(k) = 2<sup>k</sup>T(0) + 3k + k(k + 1) / 2

This does not match the pattern you'd get from T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + 1:

- T(0) = T(0)
- T(1) = 2T(0) + 1
- T(2) = 2(2T(0) + 1) + 1 = 4T(0) + 3
- T(3) = 2(4T(0) + 3) + 1 = 8T(0) + 7
- ...
- T(k) = 2<sup>k</sup>T(0) + 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1.

So it seems that either there was a miscommunication somewhere or the answer provided to you was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer does make sense, however, my professor did calculate T(n-1) and then got T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) + 1. Not sure if this would make a difference in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible considering that there's a +3 term at the end. Perhaps you should just ask the professor and see how they did this?